# computing the boundary of a union of polytopes

Tags: computational-geometry, polyhedra

Let $P_1,\dots ,P_m\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be $m<\infty$ [convex polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope#Convex_polytopes) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $U:=\bigcup_{j} P_j$ their set-theoretic union. What algorithms are known for computing the boundary $\partial U$ of $U$?

Note that $U$ would not always be convex, might have a nontrivial fundamental group, etc.

A naive algorithm I can think about would start from $\partial P_1$, intersect each facet of $P_2$ with it, obtaining $\partial (P_1\cup P_2)$, etc. 
A less naive point of view might involve working with measures supported on $P_j$'s and inclusion/exclusion in some way.

Any references on this sort of questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but may help with: "Any references on this sort of questions?"

Computing the convex hull of the union of two polytopes $P_1 \cup P_2$
is NP-hard:

> Tiwary, Hans Raj. "On the hardness of computing intersection, union and Minkowski sum of polytopes." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 40, no. 3 (2008): 469-479. [Author preliminary PDF download](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~hansraj/publications/minkowski_dcg.pdf).

But the computation is polynomial for special polytopes:

> Balas, Egon. "On the convex hull of the union of certain polyhedra." *Operations Research Letters* 7, no. 6 (1988): 279-283. [Journal link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167637788900582).
>
> Conforti, Michele, Marco Di Summa, and Yuri Faenza. "Balas formulation for the union of polytopes is optimal." [arXiv:1711.00891](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00891) (2017).

---

**Added**.
Specializing to $\mathbb{R}^3$, there is an algorithm
that constructs the boundary of the union,
which runs in $O(k^3 + kn \log k \log n)$ expected time,
where $k$ is the number of polyhedra and $n$ is the 
total number of faces:

> Aronov, Boris, Micha Sharir, and Boaz Tagansky. "The union of convex polyhedra in three dimensions." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 26, no. 6 (1997): 1670-1688.
>   [Journal link](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539793250755?journalCode=smjcat)
>   
>             
>   [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Aronov, Sharir, Tagansky.</sup>

---

Subsequently there was a specialized extension to $\mathbb{R}^4$:

> Aronov, Boris, Alon Efrat, Vladlen Koltun, and Micha Sharir. "On the union of κ-round objects in three and four dimensions." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 36, no. 4 (2006): 511-526. [Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-006-1263-x).

Comment: The question seems to be about the boundary of set theoretical union, rather than convex hull.

Comment: Indeed, it is about the boundary of a not always convex object.

Comment: A related to the complexity question - how about the case of fixed dimension (e.g. $n=3$).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Yes, I realize that my original post doesn't directly answer your question. Incidentally, it is also NP-hard to compute $P_1 \cap P_2$.

Comment: Thanks, these are very helpful references.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Just a guess, but I would expect $\sim O(n^d)$ in dimension $d$, where $n$ represents some combinatorial measure of the polytope's complexity.